# Tracking changes in a list at item level

Tags: list, version-history

What I need to do is keep track of a rather large list on SharePoint, when a user makes a change to a value in a particular column the new value should be displayed along with a Y to denote the item has changed. e.g old value `Z000` new value `Z001 , Y`.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Changes are tracked in a list by enabling version history. This can be found by browsing List Settings > Version settings -> Item Version History. Click Yes in Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?

Comment: After enabling version history on a list as explained by @NadeemYousuf, you can view changes by clicking on an item and selecting "View history"

Comment: Hi Guys is there a way to view the version history of a complete list rather than individually?

Comment: Not ootb. You can use JavaScript to get version history of all items and display the results in a list.

Comment: You can add the Version Column in your view, it will give you the latest version number.

Answer (score 3):

As other says.

- You need to enable the version'ing on your List to track the updates
  on the List item.`List Settings > Version settings -> Item Version
  History`
- Once You enabled the version then you can check it either by the item properties or Add the [Version Column in your View](http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-document-management/add-version-column-sharepoint-document-library.htm), That column will display latest version number.

Also check these may help you:

http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-display-all-versions-in.html

http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/amarender-peddamalku/sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-extract-the-version-history

Answer (score 0):

This is OOTB not possible. What you want is to check in the previous versions of an item each fields value and if a field was changed, add an ", Y" to the current value of that field in the lists view.

I would prefer using JSLink.

Answer (score 0):

Write a workflow that holds the current value of your column in a variable, then waits for the value of your column to change, then set the value of your column to the value in the variable concatenated with `, Y.

However, I don't see how you're going to deal with more than one change. If it changes again after the initial change, you'd end up with `[value], Y, Y`

Answer (score 0):

I think here workflow is the best option. Let it trigger in item update and you can check in a if statement inside workflow logic. I feel designer workflow should work.

Comment: Designer workflows run AFTER the item is updated, and there's no way to retrieve previous values in that context, so this is not an option :)