# Capturing inital Start Date vs Actual Start Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Hoping someone can help me with a way to capture the initial start date vs the actual start date to record actual lag between the dates.......What I am trying to achieve is a high level daily task plan:

Start of week, resource lists out the following:

```
Task: 12345678

Day: 20/03/2017

Duration: 5hrs
```

End of week, resource updates Yes or No if completed, which if not completed will become part of the Backlog:

```
Task: 12345678

Day: 20/03/2017

Duration: 5hrs

Completed: No
```

Few weeks later at the start of week, resource updates the same task with a new date:

```
Task: 12345678

Day: 20/05/2017

Duration: 5hrs

Completed: No
```

How can I implement a way to record the original date against the revised date using the same field?

Appreciate any assistance on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to can capture the initial value of a specific field.

1. The simplest one is Enabling versioning for your list.

   - in this case, you can track all changes occurred on your list item.

[image]

**To enable versioning:**

- Open your list > List Setting > Version Settings > Select **Yes** for `Create a version each time you edit an item in this list?` and specify the number of versions.

[image]

**To view version history**

- select your item > click on `...` Version History.

[image]

2. The second solution is to Create a new field called `previous start date` then Create a simple workflow that will capture the value of the old start date and update `previous start date` with this value.

Comment: Thank you for your response M.Qassas - as there will be a large amount of updates, entries and users updating this SP List - tracking via versioning I don't think wld be the best option, so am leaning towards the workflow option........To keep it simple, something along the lines of "when you item created"; "Date" from Day field is recorded in field of previous?

Comment: I don't catch your question ! could you elaborate more ? what is the issue of using versioning and what you need to do with workflow else what I have mentioned in my answer :)

Comment: Also, you can see all possible solution at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125271/tracking-changes-in-a-list-at-item-level

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra Field and use a Workflow to update it,
you can use an (extra) Calculated Column to do the Duration calculation.

If you go the Item Versioning route you need extra coding to do that calculation,
since every version is essentially a New Item and Formulas can't access other Versions

So I would say Workflow is the easiest, not Versioning as M.Qassas says